# Cite with author's initial in biblatex-chicago without rewriting bibliography

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I originally wrote my thesis in LaTeX according to a Chicago referencing style that called for the author's full name, e.g.:

Firstname Lastname, *Title* (Publication city, year).

However, for publication I am now supposed to use only the author's first initial, thus (even for first citation, and in the bibliography):

F. Lastname, *Title* (Publication city, year).

Is there any way to tell biblatex-chicago to use initials in this way without manually updating each entry in my .bib file? My base setup looked something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}

@book{lastname19,
author = {Lastname, Firstname},
title = {Book with a name},
year = {2019},
address = {Publication City},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\title{Citing some stuff}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

Some text with a footnote.\autocite{lastname19}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'd rather not have to go change the bib entry to read {Lastname, F.}, and the same for several hundred other works, just for this one publication. But since it would also have to take into account complicated names (for instance, what if it's {Lastname, Firstname M.}, can I get F. M. Lastname?), I'm not sure if I'm being optimistic here.

Comment: The option `giveninits=true` will abbreviate given (first) names to initials.

Comment: Thank you! It's great there's such a straightforward option. (Out of curiosity, where could I have found out about this, since it doesn't seem to be in the Biblatex-chicago documentation?)

Comment: It's a standard `biblatex` feature, so it is probably not mentioned in the `biblatex-chicago` documentation explicitly. It is documented in the `biblatex` manual. Of course the `biblatex` docs have more than 300 pages, so you need to be lucky or know what you are looking for. (In this particular case things are complicated by the fact that '`giveninits`' is not actually documented itself, instead it is documented as part of `<namepart>inits` where `<namepart>` may be `given` or any other name part).

Comment: OK, that makes sense, I appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `biblatex` option `giveninits` abbreviates all given (first) names to initials. `biblatex-chicago` has no issue at all accepting that option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lastname19,
  author  = {Lastname, Firstname},
  title   = {Book with a name},
  year    = {2019},
  address = {Publication City},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,giveninits,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text with a footnote.\autocite{lastname19}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: F. Lastname, Book with a name (Publication City, 2019).]